# Spring CallableStatementCreator

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

Hi I m new to spring.I ve tried accessing a stored proc using CallableStatementCreator ,but i get foll error.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'SampleDataSource' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [StoredProcCallApplication-config.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool

**StoredProcCall.java**

```
package Utility;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator;
public class StoredProcCall implements CallableStatementCreator {
    @Override
    public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection arg0)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CallableStatement cs=arg0.prepareCall("call test_proc(?,?)");
        cs.setString(1,"Vivek");
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        return cs;}}
```

**TestCallImpl.java**

```
package com;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import Utility.StoredProcCall;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;
import Utility.StoredProcCall;
public class TestCallImpl {
    StoredProcCall storedproccall=null;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {this.jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    public StoredProcCall getstoredproc()
    {
    return storedproccall;
    }
    public void setstoredproc(StoredProcCall storedproccall)
        {
        this.storedproccall=storedproccall;
        }
    public void callProc()
    {
    List l=new ArrayList();
    l.add(new SqlParameter("ename",OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    l.add(new SqlOutParameter("cur",OracleTypes.CURSOR,new RowMapper()
    {
    @Override
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Map m=new HashMap();
            m.put("empno",arg0.getInt("empno"));
            m.put("ename",arg0.getString("ename"));

            return m;   }}));
Map results=this.jdbcTemplate.call(new StoredProcCall(),l);
results.put("ename","Vivek");
System.out.println(results.get("ename"));}}
```

**StoredProcCallApplication-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans ---> 
 <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" > 
 <property name="dataSource" ref="SampleDataSource">
</property> </bean> 

<bean id="SampleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" scope="singleton">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername"/> 
  <property name="username" value="admin" />
   <property name="password" value="admin" /> 
    </bean>
         <bean id="storedproccall" class="Utility.StoredProcCall"> 
           </bean> 
          <bean id="TestClass" class="com.TestCallImpl"> 
      <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
       </bean> </beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: `org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool`

You need both [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) **and** [Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) on your classpath.

It looks like you only have DBCP.

Comment: +1 That's the kind of issue us Maven users never think of (because req'd dependencies are pulled automatically)

Comment: @Sean: Fair, but I don't *want* my required dependencies pulled in automatically, I want to *know* what's going in...

Comment: you *can* always know what's going on (exclude dependencies, set different versions etc.), but you don't *have to* know what's going on :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [apache commons / dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) on your classpath

```
<bean id="SampleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" ...
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's the Maven dependency (assuming you use Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: hi i don use maven.i have both the jars on my classpath.this s d xml file.

Comment: <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" > 
 <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource">
</property></bean> <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin@server"/> 
  <property name="username" value="ad"/><property name="password" value="ad"/></bean><bean id="storedproccall" class="Utility.StoredProcCall"></bean><bean id="TestClass" class="com.TestCallImpl"><property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>

Comment: @raj that's not a comment. either add to your question or post anew question